# D3 group bar chart - update graph on legend click

Tags: d3.js

I have a group bar chart . Fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/vxjdLkpp/

I want to update the bars on select of legends.

```
 legendRect.on("click", function() {


        });
```

I am getting the click but how to show hide bars?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide the bars in the two carts when a user clicks the legend. To do that you could simply add an attribute with a display of none.

```
legendRect.on("click", function() {
    bar.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("display", "none") 
    mini_bar.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("display", "none")
});
```

Comment: Thanks .. I used a similar kind of approach on legendText.